# How to increase time-effeciency of plotting complicated function?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

A newbie here: I am trying to use `ContourPlot` to plot Intensity in a strongly focus laser beam. However this intensity is a function of not so trivial integrals, so it is taking very long to plot (actually waited for 30 minutes, then I gave it up). Is there any way to speed this up? I am most likely doing something the wrong way.

Here it is: [image: code]

Code :

```
(* Define constants *)
θmax = 75. Degree;
f0 = 2.;
n = 1.5;
λ = 500.*10^-9;
k = 2.*3.14/λ;

fw[θ_] := Exp[-(Sin[θ]^2)/(f0^2*Sin[θmax]^2)]

I00[ρ_, z_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  fw[θ]*Sqrt[Cos[θ]]*Sin[θ]*(1 + Cos[θ])*
   BesselJ[0, k*ρ*Sin[θ]]*
   Exp[I*k*z*Cos[θ]], {θ, 0, θmax}]
I01[ρ_, z_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  fw[θ]*Sqrt[Cos[θ]]*Sin[θ]^2*
   BesselJ[1, k*ρ*Sin[θ]]*
   Exp[I*k*z*Cos[θ]], {θ, 0, θmax}]
I02[ρ_, z_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  fw[θ]*Sqrt[Cos[θ]]*Sin[θ]*(1 - Cos[θ])*
   BesselJ[2, k*ρ*Sin[θ]]*
   Exp[I*k*z*Cos[θ]], {θ, 0, θmax}]

 (* Intenisty *)
 Intensity[x_, y_, z_] := ((I00[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z] + 
       I02[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z]*Cos[2*ArcTan[y/x]])^2 + (I02[
        Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z]*
       Sin[2*ArcTan[y/x]])^2 - (I01[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z]*
       Cos[ArcTan[y/x]])^2 )
```

Comment: Posting code in a copyable format is much more appreciated than posting pictures of code.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that (i am new to stackexchange too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the best way is to plot without adaptive sampling of `DensityPlot`/`ContourPlot`, i.e. use `ListDensityPlot`/`ListContourPlot` instead.

I try 51×51 points here. You can go lower first just to test the waiting time; just change the denominators. (You may get `NIntegrate::izero` but `ListDensityPlot`/`ListContourPlot` will just skip those parts of `data` anyway.)

```
data = Flatten[#, 1] & @ Table[
  {x, z, Re[Intensity[x, 0, z]]},
  {x, -1.5λ, 1.5λ, 3λ / 50},
  {z, -λ, λ, 2λ / 50}
];
```

Then either

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: Density plot]

or

```
ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: @Staty You're welcome. You may want to click the check mark next to my answer. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, sure :)