# Plotting results of 'Do' loop in contour graph

Tags: plotting, matrix

I want to plot the results of a 'do' loop as a contour graph:

```
z = Reap[
  Do[
   Do[
    Sow[
     NIntegrate[Sin[a + b*x], {x, -10, 10}]
     ],
    {b, 0, 6, 0.5}
    ],
   {a, 0, 5, 0.5}
   ]
  ]
```

I get a list of values, but I'm not sure of the best way to rearrange everything to be able to plot a `b` vs `a` contour of `z`.

Comment: Would `Table` and `ListContourPlot` be any help?

Comment: Related: [(97293)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97293), [(104318)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104318)

Answer (score 2):

Why numerically integrate when you can precisely integrate?

```
ArrayPlot@(z=Table[
  Integrate[Sin[a + b x], {x, -10, 10}], 
  {b, 0, 6, 0.5}, 
  {a, 0, 5, 0.5}])
```

or

```
ListPlot[z, 
Joined -> True,
PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Yes, but I've just posted a MWE - I'm working on an integral that may not have an analytical solution.

Comment: What is the integral you seek?  By the way, you should almost never use `Do` in *Mathematica*... there are almost always superior ways to iterate, most notably `Table`.

Comment: Since you're interested, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692773/cauchy-principal-value-of-integral-with-undefined-point and I want to vary the `1` and `4`, like `a` and `b` in this example.